# Syntax Highlight in Windows 8 RT Metro

Tags: .net, microsoft-metro, richtextbox

So i was wondering  if anyone knew of a good way to do syntax highlighting in Windows 8 Windows Store Apps ,using say a RichTextBox ,am a bit confused how to access the Itextranges in the new API.

Edit:I want to use C#

Answer (score 0):

If you develop your App with HTML5, you can use a JavaScript library to accomplish this. Say, [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) or [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).

Comment: That's true ,i forgot to mention if was going to do this with C# specifically.